# How do I get the text within HTML tags not included in .content?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the text from pages like this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/p22217 into a string. In particular the block of text in DBSOURCE

I've seem multiple suggestions for using soup.findall(text=true) and the like but it comes up with nothing. Anything from before at least 2018 or so also seems to be outdated (I'm using python 3.7). I think the problem is that the content I want is outside the range of r.text and r.content; when I search with ctrl F the part I'm looking for just isn't there.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/P22217"

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

PageInfo = soup.find("pre", attrs={"class":"genbank"})

print(PageInfo)
```

The result of this and other attempts is "None". No error message, it just doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this instead as the page depends on xmlhttprequests

**Code :**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests,re

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/P22217"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,features='html.parser')
pageId = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'ncbi_uidlist'})['content']

api = requests.get('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id={}'.format(pageId))

data = re.search(r'DBSOURCE([\w\s\n\t.:,;()-_]*)KEYWORD',api.text)
print(data.group(1).strip())
```

**Demo Code :** [Here](https://repl.it/repls/TrainedEnchantedExtensions)

**Explanation :**

- The request to url will help getting the id of the product you are asking for where exist in the meta of the pages.
- by getting the id the second request will use the website api to get you the description you are asking for. A regex pattern wil be used to separate the wanted part and the unwanted part.

**Regex :**

```
DBSOURCE([\w\s\n\t.:,;()-_]*)KEYWORD
```

**Demo Regex :** [Here](https://regex101.com/r/CguscM/1)

Answer (score 0):

The page is doing XHR call in order to get the information you are looking for.
The call is to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=135747&db=protein&report=genpept&conwithfeat=on&show-cdd=on&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000

and it returns

```
<div class="sequence">
<a name="locus_P22217.3"></a><div class="localnav"><ul class="locals"><li><a href="#comment_P22217.3" title="Jump to the comment section of this record">Comment</a></li><li><a href="#feature_P22217.3" title="Jump to the feature table of this record">Features</a></li><li><a href="#sequence_P22217.3" title="Jump to the sequence of this record">Sequence</a></li></ul></div>
<pre class="genbank">LOCUS       TRX1_YEAST               103 aa            linear   PLN 18-SEP-2019
DEFINITION  RecName: Full=Thioredoxin-1; AltName: Full=Thioredoxin I;
            Short=TR-I; AltName: Full=Thioredoxin-2.
ACCESSION   P22217
VERSION     P22217.3
**DBSOURCE**    UniProtKB: locus TRX1_YEAST, accession <a href="https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P22217">P22217</a>;
            class: standard.
            extra accessions:D6VY45
            created: Aug 1, 1991.
```

...

So do HTTP call from your code in order to get the data.